# Como puedo ordenar una lista de ID

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy tratando de ordenar una lista de pedidos de manera ascendente mediante la referencia de los pedidos pero al momento de ejecutar el método que trate de usar me manda el mensaje System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Char,System.String]

Como puedo arreglar el metodo para que me muestre los datos correctamente

```
<tbody>
    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr class="c-table__row">
               
                @{ 
                    var ordenarPo = from Po in item.Referencia
                                    orderby item.Referencia
                                    select Po.ToString();
                }
                <td class="c-table__cell">
                   @ordenarPo
                </td>
                
</tbody>
```

Comment: En MVC, acostúmbrate a a pensar que el Modelo que retorna el Controlador debe estar prácticamente listo parar que sea renderizado en la Vista, procesar cosas en la vista... Como que no es el objetivo. De poder se puede, pero, ¿estás seguro que quieres romper el patrón?

Comment: Por cierto, lo que hace tu código: estás llamando una lista de strings y quieres mostrar esa lista, no un elemento, tampoco iterar la lista.